# Accept parameter with different datatypes?

Tags: swift

I have a function which accepts a parameter of `[String: AnyObject]?`

```
func myfunction(parameters: [String: AnyObject]?) {
    // I handle everything here
}
```

In most cases I normally just send a dictionary of `<String, AnyObject>` which works fine.

In the case I am having an issue with now I trying to add a parameter which has a Dictionary as a value.

```
let parameters = [
    "products_in_basket": [
        "id": product.Id,
        "size": 12,
        "colour": "red",
        "quantity": 1
    ],
    "shipping_address_id": self.currentAddress!.Id,
    "shipping_option": 0,
    "payment_card_id": self.currentCard!.Id
]

// All above works ok until now
myfunction(parameters: parameters) {

}
```

When I call myfunction I get the error:

> 'NSDictionary' is not convertible to '[String : AnyObject]'; did you mean to downcast?

Now the error is pretty self explanatory, but i'm not sure how I can allow my function to allow this data type and still work with current data types.

I am using this function in quite a few places and don't want to duplicate the exact same logic just to accept a different parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you don't have to downcast, you should just help the compiler understand what happens by explicitly giving the right type to your dictionary:

```
let parameters: [String:AnyObject] = [
    "products_in_basket": [
        "id": product.Id,
        "size": 12,
        "colour": "red",
        "quantity": 1
    ],
    "shipping_address_id": self.currentAddress!.Id,
    "shipping_option": 0,
    "payment_card_id": self.currentCard!.Id
]
```

That way the compiler won't ask you to downcast, and your function will work as you expect.

*Note: this is for Swift 1.2 - no need to explicitly set the type with Swift 2 (type will be inferred as `[String:NSObject]` but it will work nonetheless).*

Comment: Thanks simple answer :)